# Checking if each value is assigned a unique name

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need a way to find and list when the same user is assigned to a certain value, say '1' and '2', rather than a different user being assigned to each. For example:

Should be:

```
name  value   date

bill   1    6-25-2013
bob    2    6-25-2013
joe    1    6-25-2013
dan    2    6-25-2013
```

Not:

```
name  value   date

bill   1    6-25-2013
bill   2    6-25-2013
joe    1    6-25-2013
joe    2    6-25-2013
```

I need a way to list the ones that are not correct, where the same person is assigned to '1' and '2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name, count(distinct value) from table group by name having count(distinct value) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, count(*) AS c FROM tablename HAVING c > 1
```